# How to activate jupyterlab-vim for jupyter-lab-4.0.2?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I try to run the install command `pip install jupyterlab-vim`, which I found in https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-vim#install

Result of executing `jupyter labextension list`:

- messages:

  ```
  JupyterLab v4.0.2
  /opt/conda/share/jupyter/labextensions
          jupyterlab_pygments v0.2.2 enabled  X (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
          @axlair/jupyterlab_vim v0.16.0 enabled  X (python, jupyterlab_vim)  


     The following extensions are outdated:
          jupyterlab_pygments
          @axlair/jupyterlab_vim

     Consider running "jupyter labextension update --all" to check for updates.
  ```
- picture of messages:

  [image]

From the result of `X`, it seems like something went wrong, but I can't find the more detailed error message.

What I've tried:

- The most relative source I can find is : [How to get Vim editor extension working?](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-get-vim-editor-extension-working/19272), but I don't think the solution fit for me, because I don't use any virtual environment.
- Once I downgrade jupyterlab to 3.2.4, the command `pip install jupyterlab-vim` work again.

**What should I do to repair this issue?**

My jupyter lab environment:

```
jupyter_client            8.3.0
jupyter_core              5.3.1
jupyter-events            0.6.3
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0
jupyter_server            2.7.0
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4
jupyterlab                4.0.2
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2
jupyterlab_server         2.23.0
jupyterlab-vim            0.16.0
```

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-activate-jupyterlab-vim-for-jupyter-lab-4-0-2/20325?u=fomightez). Those coming upon this post may want to check there for pertinent information if not answered here.

Answer (score 1):

The jupyterlab-vim extension (version 0.16) works with jupyterlab 3.6.5, but not jupyterlab 4. I suggest that you pin the version that works with one of the lines of shell code below and submit an issue at https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-vim/issues.

```
pip install jupyterlab==3.6.5
conda install -yc conda-forge jupyterlab==3.6.5
mamba install -yc conda-forge jupyterlab==3.6.5
```